# Sensors that are also actuators?

Tags: sensor, actuator

this is more of a theoretical question, and I do not know if this is suited for this QA site at all,  but at school I was asked to provide 3 examples of sensors (in the narrow sense) that are also actuators.
I cannot find any information for the life of me. The only example I can find are piezoelectric sensors, but I am not sure if this is correct.

A sensor in the narrow sense is a device which reacts to a signal/stimulus from a electrical signal.

Comment: Due to the [observer effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)) all sensors are actuators ;-)

Comment: The last sentence is not clear: the sensor in that sense creates the signal from the stimulus, not vice versa

Comment: @noah1989 not always: potentiometric sensors are an example of not perturbing sensors, as they don't alter the position of the cursor

Comment: @clabacchio the position of the cursor is slightly altered by the electrons flowing through the pot ;-) but also the temperature increases (significantly sometimes!)

Comment: @noah1989 mh I'd say as more plausible that the presence of the pot itself may alter the positioning accuracy of the object, but it may also be true...uhm...

Comment: @clabacchio I once used a potentiometer to control some 12V fans on my desk. After adding more fans I learned that a pot can work well as a "fire ignition" actuator :D

Comment: @noah1989 oh well, that's quite unusual :P but I was mostly referring to linear potentiometer used to sense the position of an object, more than to regulate a current

Comment: somewhat related: [Difference between sensors and transducers](https://makersconfidential.blogspot.com/2015/04/difference-between-sensors-and-transducers.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Examples:

- (As you said) a piezoelectric transducer. It can produce sounds, or work as a microphone.
- An electromechanical speaker. The same device can act as a speaker, or as a microphone (old walkie-talkie toys use that fact).
- Even an LED. If you apply forward current through an LED, it produces light, and it is an actuator. If you bias it with a reverse voltage, and measure the reverse current (very low), you can measure light with it, and it will be a sensor.
- An antenna. It can transmit and receive (even simultaneously, at different frequencies, or using other discrimination schemes).
- An electric motor. You can use it to produce and to detect (and measure) movement.
- Even an NTC/PTC resistor (which is supposed to be "only" a sensor), could also work as an actuator, if I inject enough current so as to modify its temperature, and that of its surroundings. I could use it to keep a (very) small mass at a constant temperature, in a low ambient temperature environment, and a single device would suffice as a sensor and actuator.

Comment: About the speaker: you can also use your headphones as microphones, I did it in some cases

Answer (score 2):

To add some other cases:

- To some extent, a resistor is also a temperature sensor/actuator
- Peltier cells are also temperature/electricity converters
- Inductors convert magnetic field into electric current and vice versa
- Batteries are also a sort of chemical/electrical transducer, and they can work in both senses
- A resistor can be considered also as current/voltage transducer, and it can be considered a current sensor, since usually the output (for ADC conversion) is a voltage

Comment: Sorry, we overlapped the comment about resistors :-)

Comment: @Telaclavo ouch :) no problem, I would remove it because yours is more complete but it's also a bit more specific (all resistors are temperature sensitive)